# Handle logged in user model and view in backbone js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a login form in my backbone application and I would like to display a view with the status of the user. My login view looks like this:

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#login-form"),
    events: {
        'click button': 'login',
    },
    initialize: function () { },
    login: function (event) {
        var self = this;
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = '/api/auth/login';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: this.$el.serialize(),
            success: function () {}
        });
    }
});
```

What is the best way of saving the user object, display a login status view and restore it if the page is reloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole process looks like this.

1. User hits the website.
2. A userSession model is created and assign to the application scope `App.currentUser = new App.Models.UserSession()`
3. Do fetch with currentUser `App.currentUser.fetch()`
4. According to the return, if there's an existing user session, display the user info. Else, show the login view.
5. Login view logic, in the success callback. `App.currentUser.set(response)`